# suggest a way to make key in medoo

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, redis, medoo

I use medoo as database framework and I add caching using redis but there is a problem with it .
I create key like this blow :

```
    public function select(string $table, $join, $columns = null, $where = null): ?array
    {
      $redisKey = md5(json_encode([$table , $where]));
// and add it to Redis and etc.
// https://github.com/catfan/Medoo/blob/master/src/Medoo.php#L1581
```

but when i try to make same key with same way at update or delete to remove old cache , it doesn't work !
can you pls show me a way to figure it out ?

Comment: Please DEFINE **doesnt work**

Comment: what i code , it cant make same key as the select method in update and delete method .i do same $redisKey = md5(json_encode([$table , $where])); there